# Function not calling properly

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, calling-convention

```
def main():

    def load():
        name=0
        count=0
        totalpr=0
        name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
        while name != '-999':
            count=count+1
            shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
            pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
            sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
            commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
            name = input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

    def calc():
        amount_paid=shares*pp
        commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
        amount_sold=shares*sp
        commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
        profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
        totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss

    def print():
        print("\nStock Name:", name)
        print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
        print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
        print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
        print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
        print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))
        print("Total Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))
        return main()




load() #to input the values
calc()
print()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

Should I be putting in variable names into `def load():`, `def calc():` and `def print():`?

As I run it now, it says `"load"` is not defined. How would I go about defining `load`? And for that matter, if I didn't define `def calc():` and `def print():` how do I define those?

I do properly call them at the end of the code, in the order that I'd like to call them -- `load`, `calc`, and then `print`.

Is my "`return main()`" the right thing to do? I don't know, I Just want this code to run properly without error that's all. I'm under the impression that I'm just missing a few things. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've defined `load` inside of `main` so it's not visible outside of `main`. Why did you define functions inside of `main` if you weren't going to use `main`?

Comment: Okay, how do I use main while still calling with load(), calc() and print()?

Comment: I personally don't like using main functions. I find them superfluous. Many vehemently disagree. But if you are, usually you define your functions *outside* of `main`, then call the functions in the order you want *inside* of `main`. Then the last line of the file is a call to `main()`.  There is no need to return anything from `main`.

Comment: Unrelated, but see here on how to do string formatting correctly. https://pyformat.info/

Comment: So now I have [in order from the top] def load(): followed by def calc():, def print(): and finally def main(): and inside def main(): is load(), calc() and print(). But when I *run* it, I get absolutely nothing. The output is blank.

Comment: Note that once one of your functions is named `print`, you cannot use the builtin `print` anymore!

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `load()` inside the scope of `main()`. This means you cannot use the function outside of `main()`.

The easy solution is that you should put your function defines for load, calc, and print outside of the definition of `main()` (btw, call it something else like `print_stock info`, print is already a function!)

You also do not need to `return main()`. I am unsure what you are trying to do, but it is not necessary at all.

Comment: What I'm trying to do:

Comment: def main():

load() 
calc()
print()

Comment: I'd like to write the main() function to call the above functions similar to the comment above

Comment: you can absolutely do that.

define your functions above main, and then call them inside of main.

Comment: So now I have [in order from the top] def load(): followed by def calc():, def print(): and finally def main(): and inside def main(): is load(), calc() and print(). But when I run it, I get absolutely nothing. The output is blank.

Comment: I would create a new question for that - or post a snippet somewhere like gisthub so I can have a look

Answer (score 0):

yikes.
your first mistake: calling a function in another function. Maybe you meant to do

```
class Main:
    def load(self):
        #do a thing
```

then you'd have to do

```
main = Main()
main.load()
```

your second mistake was defining a new a print() function that uses print functions, as one already exists. Rename it, as that will cause a huge error

Comment: Definitely no need for a class. This isn't Java.

Comment: Furthermore, calling functions from within other functions is perfectly normal  (unless, of course, you're referring to the infinite recursion that occurs by nesting these functions within one another).

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal working example to illustrate how one can solve what you are trying to do.

```
# helper for interpreting input
import ast
#: initial starting values
thing, count, cost, total = 'Nothing', 0, 0, 0

# define all functions at module indentation
def get_user_input():
    global thing, count, cost  # write to the GLOBAL names thing, count and cost
    thing = input('What have you?')  # ask for a string
    count = ast.literal_eval(input('How much do you have?'))  # ask for a string and interpret it: "3.2" => float
    cost = ast.literal_eval(input('How much does each cost?'))

def compute():
    global total  # write to global name total
    total = count * cost  # can read from global names

def pretty_print():  # not named print! we still need print to print!
    print("You have", count, thing)
    print("At", cost, "each, that makes", total, "in total")

# call functions at module indentation
get_user_input()  # ducks, 3, 42
compute()
pretty_print()
# You have 3 ducks
# At 42 each, that makes 126 in total
```

One thing to warn you about: working with global variables is generally a bad idea. For a small script it's fine, but you've already messed up the basics - globals are tricky, so avoid them whenever possible. If you just want to run these commands, do not write them as functions, execute them directly. Basically, leave away the `def ...` and `global ...` lines and put everything on the same indentation, then remove the last three lines.

If you really want to store and print multiple things, you need to use containers. Just assigning to a value in a loop, e.g. `thing = input('What have you?')`, will leave it at the last value entered. Instead, you need a container like a `list`. You can then `append` additional values to it.

```
container = []  # [] is a list literal
for _ in range(3):  # non-infinite loop
    next_thing = ast.literal_eval(input('Place your order...\n'))
    container.append(next_thing)
print("You ordered", container)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. So now I have [in order from the top] def load(): followed by def calc():, def print(): and finally def main(): and inside def main(): is load(), calc() and print(). But when I run it, I get absolutely nothing. The output is blank.

Comment: It's for a school assignment -- what was a straight line of code was told to be transformed into 3 functions. That's why it's really clunky.

Comment: If you have tried this and still have `def load`, `def calc` and `def print`, you should definitely try it again... Hint: you should not have `def print`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def load():    
    global name
    global count
    global shares
    global pp
    global sp
    global commission
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    count =0
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        calc()
        display()
        name=input("\nEnter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

def calc():
    global amount_paid
    global amount_sold
    global profit_loss
    global commission_paid_sale
    global commission_paid_purchase
    global totalpr
    totalpr=0
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss

def display():
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    load()


main()

print("\nTotal Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))
```